# Co-tenant entered my bedroom; how can I prove someone else unlocked my door?

Tags: canada, rental-property, british-columbia

I'm not looking for legal advice!

I live in a shared house. There are 4 other people. We each have our own lease. Tonight I came home and noticed my bedroom door had been opened, even though I'm sure I closed and locked it. Also my coat had been taken out of the living room and placed inside the door.

I'm suspicious the landlord of the house gave another tenant the key to my bedroom door. I share the kitchen and living room with the other tenants, but the bedroom is mine privately.

Is there anything I can do about this? Worst case scenario would this be breaking and entering? I know I need the landlords premission to change a lock but I'm thinking of going ahead and doing it. How can I prove that someone else unlocked my door?

Comment: Who do you want to prove it to?

Comment: You're in shared quarters. As soon as you share anything, you lose almost all protection and rights. Move out if you're suspicious, or change the locks and see what happens. Worst case is that they can kick you out with no notice, it's not like you're going to be facing criminal charges.

Comment: @user900: Wait what? The landlord provided interior door locks makes claiming shared area preposterous.